# Outlook with multiple calendars: How to determine the selected one with VBA?

Tags: outlook

Even though several calendars can be selected and visible in Outlook, there is only one calendar active (selected by click it). How can I determine programatically which calendar has the current focus? Is there any change event available, which allows me to disable or enable a ribbon element?

Comment: Please provide more information such as programming language and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder` to determine the current folder.